# NGINX specify variable for specific directory and index file only

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using fastcgi caching, and would like to specify which URLs the cache should be active on.

I use a rewrite rule to determine which controller file to access, and set any query parameters dynamically

I want to specify URLs in which the cache is activated, and those in which it is inactive, this is my code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;

    set %skip_cache 1;        #this is the variable that I want to set to 0 on specific URLS

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html @php;
    }
    location @php {         
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)$ $1.php last;
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)/(.*)$ $1.php?q=$2 last;
    }


    location /user/ {
        set $skip_cache 0;
    }

    location /objects/ {
        set $skip_cache 0;
    }

    location ~ \.php$  {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        ...etc...

    #cache parameters
    fastcgi_param FASTCGI_CACHE 1;
    fastcgi_cache cfcache;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 30s;
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
    add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;  
}
```

as you can see, the variable $skip_cache is set to 1 by default, and I would like to white list URLs for caching.

An example I would like cached is `domain.com`, `domain.com/user/123` and `domain.com/objects/456`

Currently, if I browse to `/user/123`, the result is a `404` error, as I believe that location block with the variable setting is being used exclusively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a variable based on the original request, you should use a `map` directive with the `$request_uri` variable. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $skip_cache {
    default      1;
    ~^/user/     0;
    ~^/objects/  0;
}
server {
    ...
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's working great! Do you know how to make it hit the index file as well, so for example `domain.com` which is rewritten to `domain.com/index.php` how to get that index file to also be white listed?

Comment: You can add a `/  0;` line and a `~^/index.php  0;` line to the `map`.